# VSync turning itself on in Driver: San Francisco

Tags: driver-san-francisco

Well, i can declare it as bug. I installed Driver : SF today and played it a little. I saw a little performance issues so, i went to Settings >> Video for adjustments. Well, there `VSync` was ON. I turned it OFF and saved settings. But whenever i do that, the `VSync` still remain ON everytime. I can't get it to permanently OFF. Is there anything to fix it? Somebody had a same issue? I can gain some FPS if that get OFF.

Comment: Are you playing on a monitor or a tv?

Comment: @k1DBLITZ i am playing on laptop screen :D